# DynamicData in MSTest does does not show correctly in TestExplorer

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

I have the following test method using `DynamicData`

```cs
  [DataTestMethod]
        [DoNotParallelize]
        [DynamicData(nameof(GetFilteredDataTestConfig), typeof(DataTest), 
            DynamicDataSourceType.Method, DynamicDataDisplayName = nameof(GetTestDisplayNames))]
        public void RunDataTest(DataTestCase testCase)
```

where the DynamicData is fed by the `GetFilteredDataTestConfig`.

Using the following method I get the expected results in the TestExplorer TreeView.

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetFilteredDataTestConfig()
    {
        yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = "D:\\TestCase_001\\test.cfg" } };
        yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = "D:\\TestCase_002\\test.cfg" } };
        yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = "D:\\TestCase_003\\test.cfg" } };
        yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = "D:\\TestCase_004\\test.cfg" } };
        yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = "D:\\TestCase_005\\test.cfg" } };
        yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = "D:\\TestCase_006\\test.cfg" } };
        yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = "D:\\TestCase_007\\test.cfg" } };
        yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = "D:\\TestCase_008\\test.cfg" } };
        yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = "D:\\TestCase_009\\test.cfg" } };
        yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = "D:\\TestCase_010\\test.cfg" } };
    
        yield break;
    }
```

that produces this result in the TestExplorer displayed in the TreeView:

[image]

When I do the same with a for loop

```cs
  public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetFilteredDataTestConfig()
        {
            var filtered = TestHelper.FilterDataTest is not null && !TestHelper.FilterDataTest.Contains("None");

            foreach (string testFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(TestHelper.ConfigFileDirectory))
            {
                string dtcfgFileName = Path.Combine(testFolder, 

                var config = TestHelper.LoadDataTestConfig(dtcfgFileName);

                if (config.Active && TestHelper.TestType.HasFlag(config.TestType))
                {
                    yield return new object[] { new DataTestCase { FileName = dtcfgFileName, TestType = config.TestType } };
                    continue;
                }
            }

            yield break;
        }
```

The results are displayed in the right side of the TestExplorer but not in the TreeView anymore:

[image]

I have no real idea why this happens and what the difference between the two methods is.